# Can't import SVG into Next.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4, next.js

When I try to import SVG Image then the following error shows. Which loader I have to use for importing SVG images?

```
./static/Rolling-1s-200px.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2000 2000"><filter id="b"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="12" /></filter><path fill="#817c70" d="M0 0h2000v2000H0z"/><g filter="url(#b)" transform="translate(4 4) scale(7.8125)" fill-opacity=".5"><ellipse fill="#000210" rx="1" ry="1" transform="matrix(50.41098 -3.7951 11.14787 148.07886 107 194.6)"/><ellipse fill="#eee3bb" rx="1" ry="1" transform="matrix(-56.38179 17.684 -24.48514 -78.06584 205 110.1)"/><ellipse fill="#fff4bd" rx="1" ry="1" transform="matrix(35.40604 -5.49219 14.85017 95.73337 16.4 123.6)"/><ellipse fill="#79c7db" cx="21" cy="39" rx="65" ry="65"/><ellipse fill="#0c1320" cx="117" cy="38" rx="34" ry="47"/><ellipse fill="#5cb0cd" rx="1" ry="1" transform="matrix(-39.46201 77.24476 -54.56092 -27.87353 219.2 7.9)"/><path fill="#e57339" d="M271 159l-123-16 43 128z"/><ellipse fill="#47332f" cx="214" cy="237" rx="242" ry="19"/></g></svg>
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-loader

Comment: To solve this problem in next-friendly way I use next-react-svg plugin. Here is how https://stackoverflow.com/a/61854576/1762849

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You need to provide a webpack loader that will handle SVG imports, one of the famous one is [svgr](https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr).

In order to configure it to work with next, you need to add to your `next.config.js` file the usage of the loader, like that:

```js
// next.config.js
    
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      issuer: {
        test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
       // for webpack 5 use
       // { and: [/\.(js|ts)x?$/] }
      },
      
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

For more config info, [check out the docs](https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/docs/webpack/).

**Don't forget** to install [`@svgr/webpack`](https://npm.im/@svgr/webpack) first:

```sh
$ npm install --save-dev @svgr/webpack
```

**Edit**

I've added an `issuer` section which strict these svg as component only for svgs that are imported from `js / ts` files.
This allows you to configure other behaviour for `svg`s that are imported from other file types (such as `.css`)

Comment: [next-svgr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-svgr) is a higher level Next plugin implementing the same solution. it doesn't support `issuer` parameter at the moment, though.

Comment: Yeah, this is no bueno @felixmosh

Comment: for webpack5 ,use `issuer: { and: [/\.(js|ts)x?$/] }`

Comment: SVGR + Next.js - The official docs: https://react-svgr.com/docs/next

Comment: getting `ValidationError: Invalid configuration object.`

Comment: Can confirm this worked form webpack 5!:  


config.module.rules.push({
      issuer: {
        and: [/\.(js|ts)x?$/],
      },
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

Comment: You could also fix the `ValidationError` instead by specifying the test value inside the issuer object directly to the issuer like this: `issuer: /\.(js|ts)x?$/`

Comment: Is it possible to get use the imported svg as a `src` in `next/image` component? Like you can with `png` and `jpeg`'s, e.g.:

`<Image src={pngImage} />`

Comment: if you need to use the svg as a data-url, then you need to update the webpack config. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66768451/6908282)

Answer (score 56):

### The quick way: `<img>` or `<Image>`

[**Not suitable for interactive SVGs or if you intend to manipulate a SVG by external CSS/JS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web#the_quick_way_img_element)

One can use the official [`next/image`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) component or `img` tag (as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63626899/11613622)).

You just need to move your `svg` file to [`public`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) instead of `static`, and do something like this:

```
import Image from 'next/image';

// ...

<Image src="/Rolling-1s-200px.svg" width="2000" height="2000" />
```

But by using this method, the content of `svg` file will not be present directly in the response; the browser will get an [`<img src="..." ...></img>`](https://caniuse.com/svg-img) tag.

Also one needs to specify `width` and `height`, but you can calculate it from the [`viewbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute.

On Next.js v11 and above, you can also do:

```
import Image from 'next/image';

import Illustration from '../static/Rolling-1s-200px.svg';

// ...

<Image src={Illustration} />

// one needs to use `Illustration.src` to get the source URL
// <img src={Illustration.src} ... />
```

---

### Including SVG inside HTML (for webpack-5, TS)

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55180310/11613622) has shown how to do this with `webpack-4`, but since `webpack-5` is now default, I'm sharing the appropriate config. You can use it after installing [`@svgr/webpack`](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/) (`yarn add -D @svgr/webpack` or `npm install @svgr/webpack --save-dev`):

```js
// next.config.js
// https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/issues/551#issuecomment-839772396

module.exports = {
  // other configs...

  // future: { webpack5: true }, // -- not needed since Next.js v11.0.0
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: { and: [/\.(js|ts|md)x?$/] },
      use: [
        {
          loader: '@svgr/webpack',
          options: {
            prettier: false,
            svgo: true,
            svgoConfig: { plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }] },
            titleProp: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

If you are not using `options` for the loader, then you can simply write this:

```js
use: ['@svgr/webpack']
```

If you are using v6 of `@svgr/webpack` then you need to specify SVGO config like this:

```js
// ...

plugins: [
  {
    name: 'preset-default',
    params: {
      overrides: { removeViewBox: false },
    },
  },
],

// ...
```

If using typescript, you need to define proper modules (in the directory from where you are importing `svg`, or maybe add it at root as `<some-name>.d.ts` and include it `tsconfig`):

```
// index.d.ts

declare module '*.svg' {
  const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  export default ReactComponent;
}
```

Then you may use it like:

```
import Illustration from '../static/Rolling-1s-200px.svg';

// ...

<Illustration />
```

**Note**: Next.js v11.0.1+ have declared SVGs as modules exporting `any`. Your custom configuration will not override the types set by `next-env.d.ts` unless you exclude the latter. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68129058/11613622).

**[*OUTDATED ([Fixed](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/26281))*] <s>UPDATE :</s>**

If you are using Next.js v11.0.0, then you might be getting errors while importing SVGs. Please update to `v11.0.1` or above. <s>Please follow the workaround mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/26130#issuecomment-861731681).</s>

---

### Using Turbopack?

You can add `@svgr/webpack` like this:

```
// next.config.mjs

export default {
  experimental: {
    turbo: {
      rules: {
        '*.svg': {
          loaders: ['@svgr/webpack'],
          as: '*.js'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(Taken from https://x.com/leeerob/status/1755974197581603210)

Comment: can i use `.svg` from `public/` directory? currently, i created `assets/` just to use relative imports using TS like `@/assets/logo.svg` but would love to use it from `public/` only. is it possible?

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Please refer the first part of the answer. Move your SVGs to `public` and use them like this `<Image src="/svg-name.svg" height="100" width="100" />` . You can also move your assets folder directly to `public` directory; then you would need to pass `src` as `/assets/svg-name.svg`.

Comment: no, i need to import it. i dont want to use `Image` component. that part is missing from your answer & its exactly what i want to do.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 Then it's not possible. I mean you can keep a SVG in `public` or any folder, but you will need to specify whole path like `@/public/logo.svg` while importing. The second part of the answer shows this. You don't have to use `Image` component in that.

Comment: Note that: `assets` is just a conventional folder name, it is nothing that Next.js understands by itself. If you want to put the assets in `public` directory itself then it is also fine; you just need to change import statement: `import Logo from '@/public/logo.svg';` But please keep in mind that public folder is accessible by anyone visiting your site, so don't put anything confidential there.

Comment: oh yeah! next.js only understands `pages/` & `api/` i think. I use `src/` folder & `public/` folder in the same directory using aliases & I was only using aliases inside `src/` so i didn't set up aliases for `public/` & thought i could do `import Logo from '/logo.svg'` to import from `public/` but that didn't work. thanks to your both comments, it makes sense now.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 You can use a path like this: ```"@/*": ["src/*", "public/*"]``` then `import Logo from '@/Logo.svg';` will work.

Comment: Still getting "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file" and then "Error: Cannot find module '.../pages-manifest.json'" error because webpack can't read config :( Maybe it's related to sentry or next-transpile-modules but when I don't use them in config, absolute paths stop working. Guess I'll have to use prefix in imports.

Comment: @VityaSchel Can you post a different question showing what all went wrong and how to reproduce it? Discussing your query here in the comment section is not beneficial for the community. And AFAIK, the second error occurs mainly due to failure in webpack build (first error). Can you try if the solutions mentioned in this thread work: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/6287

Comment: `<Image src={Illustration} />` worked!

Comment: Could you clarify a little on where exactly you add the `plugins` part of the config? I added it to the same place as the module, EG `config.plugins.push()` however Webpack panicked. SVGs did however work for me without this plugin part altogether on v6.2.1 of svgr.

Comment: @MagnusBull You don't need that if you're not using SVGO at all. I have specified this in the answer (simply `use: ['@svgr/webpack']` will work fine). However if you're using SVGO with SVGR v6, then you need to replace the plugin array of `svgoConfig` (`plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }]` see third code block in the answer) with the shown syntax (in fifth code block).

Answer (score 33):

Install [next-images](https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images).

```sh
yarn add -D next-images
```

Create a next.config.js in your project

```js
// next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

Comment: For those using Typescript, don't forget to add:

/// <reference types="next-images" />
into your next-env.d.ts file.

Comment: How do add my custom configurations inside withImages ? When I do ` module.exports = withImages({ reactStrictMode: true, ...rest of the cofigurations })` , the build is failing. Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 20):

I personally prefer [next-react-svg](https://github.com/jeremybarbet/next-react-svg) plugin which allows to treat SVG images as React components and automatically inline them, similar to what Create React App does.

Here is how to use it:

1. Install `next-react-svg`:

```
npm i next-react-svg
```

2. Add necessary settings to `next.config.js`:

```js
const withReactSvg = require('next-react-svg')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = withReactSvg({
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/svg'),
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config
  }
})
```

**The `include` parameter is compulsory** and it points to your SVG image folder.

If you already have any plugins enabled for your Next.js, consider using [next-compose-plugins](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins) to properly combine them.

3. Import your SVGs as ordinary React components:

```js
import Logo from 'assets/svg/Logo.svg';

export default () => (
  <Logo />
);
```

That's it. From now on, Next.js will be including SVG images imported this way into the rendered markup as SVG tags.

Comment: Do you know how to use next-react-svg with storybook?

Comment: This is great thanks.  If you're coming from Create React App like I am, make sure to change your import statement of the SVG.  ie change `import { ReactComponent as MySvg } from 'src/assets/mysvg.svg'`. to `import MySvg from 'src/assets/mysvg.svg'`

Comment: That is a simple and efficient solution, Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [babel-plugin-inline-react-svg](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg)

```
import React from 'react';
import CloseSVG from './close.svg';

const MyComponent = () => <CloseSVG />;
```

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-inline-react-svg
```

```
// .babelrc
{
  "plugins": [
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

Or see the link for more instructions.

Comment: This wont work on a Typescript project for whatever reason.

Comment: 1. Absolute paths not supported 
2. You must set viewbox manually because this plugin does not import it from svg file 
3. Does not work with typescript.

Isn't there a simple solution?? Nextjs exists for many years and this question was asked in 2019!

Comment: 2023 - still just as bad...

Comment: It's somewhat better in Next.js these days. @ДенисБеспалов

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me without any other dependency

```
// In next.config.js

module.exports = {
    webpack (config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 100000
                }
            }
        });
        return config;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Pure Webpack configuration. There is no need to install anything.

Comment: @DayronGallardo "no need to install anything" Huh? You have to install @zeit/next-sass and @zeit/next-css

Comment: @BrandonDuffany no you don't have to install them. The answerer has copy-pasted their own configuration, that's why there are those utility wrappers present in the code block. You don't need to use them at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply import it via `<img>` tag.

```
<img src='./next.svg' alt='next' />
```

Just make sure that the svg is in public folder.

Comment: This answer is misleading as the context here is SVG as SVG but not as image.

Comment: using this method the svg won't show up in the browser

Answer (score 3):

With `Next.js 12.0.9` and `Webpack 5` this works for me:

```bs
yarn add --dev url-loader @svgr/webpack
```

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    webpack(config, options) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader'],
        });
    
        return config;
    },
  };
```

Comment: you don't even need `url-loader`

Comment: @deadcoder0904 for me without 'url-loader' nextjs can't load SVG and gives me error. I'm also wondering why but it's necessary.

Comment: I confirm, `url-loader` needed to make namedExport working, so you can do `export { ReactComponent as SomeSvg } from './actual.svg`. Without url loader, only `default` export is available.

Comment: This method works great. This is what I need. i needed to change the color via css just by setting the class like this

`<LogoSVG className={s.logo}/>`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use SVG files in your code **WITHOUT ANY CONFIG OR INSTALLING A DEPENDENCY** and have **complete control** on the tag's attributes, the best solution is to convert the SVG file to JSX or TSX components.

**JSX solution:**

```
export const YourSVg = ({color, width, height}) => (
   <svg fill={color} height={height} width={width}>
    ..rest of the svg tags...
   </svg>
)
```

**TSX solution:**

```
   export const YourSVg:React.FC<{color:string, width:string, height:string}> =
       ({color, width, height}) => (
          <svg color={color} height={height} width={width}>
            ..rest of the svg tags...
          </svg>
    )
```

**How to use it?**

can import it like a normal component and use it same as before

**for instance:**

```
import YourSVg from '../from the path/path


<YourSVg color='red' width='10px' height='10px/>
```

Comment: This works but requires that one shoulder an entirely new workflow for managing svg assets vs. the traditional approach of storing them in an e.g. `static/svg` directory as *.svg files.

Answer (score 2):

[How to import SVG into Next.js component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276103/how-to-import-svg-into-next-js-component)

Another solution without install any library

```
import React from "react";
export default function GoogleLogo() {
  return (
    <svg className="svgIcon-use" width="25" height="37" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
      <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
        <path
          d="M20.66 12.693c0-.603-.054-1.182-.155-1.738H12.5v3.287h4.575a3.91 3.91 0 0 1-1.697 2.566v2.133h2.747c1.608-1.48 2.535-3.65 2.535-6.24z"
          fill="#4285F4"
        />
        <path
          d="M12.5 21c2.295 0 4.22-.76 5.625-2.06l-2.747-2.132c-.76.51-1.734.81-2.878.81-2.214 0-4.088-1.494-4.756-3.503h-2.84v2.202A8.498 8.498 0 0 0 12.5 21z"
          fill="#34A853"
        />
        <path
          d="M7.744 14.115c-.17-.51-.267-1.055-.267-1.615s.097-1.105.267-1.615V8.683h-2.84A8.488 8.488 0 0 0 4 12.5c0 1.372.328 2.67.904 3.817l2.84-2.202z"
          fill="#FBBC05"
        />
        <path
          d="M12.5 7.38c1.248 0 2.368.43 3.25 1.272l2.437-2.438C16.715 4.842 14.79 4 12.5 4a8.497 8.497 0 0 0-7.596 4.683l2.84 2.202c.668-2.01 2.542-3.504 4.756-3.504z"
          fill="#EA4335"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

and use:

```
import GoogleLogo from "./GoogleLogo";

  class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <LoginLayout title="Login Page">
          <div>
            <Link href="/auth/google">
              <a className="button">
                <div>
                  <span className="svgIcon t-popup-svg">
                    <GoogleLogo />
                  </span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </LoginLayout>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the first answer, but I got an error, so this works:

```
module.exports = {
webpack(config) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.svg$/,
    use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
  });

  return config;
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next-plugin-svgr` & `next-compose-plugins` to clean up plugins (if you have):

```
// next.config.js
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withSvgr = require("next-svgr");
 
module.exports = withPlugins([
  withSvgr
  // your other plugins here
]);
```

or just `next-plugin-svgr`:

```
// next.config.js
const withSvgr = require('next-plugin-svgr');
 
module.exports = withSvgr({
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config;
  },
});
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-plugin-svgr

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways to just load the SVG as text and insert it is using the [`raw-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/).

So first install the npm package `raw-loader` via your package manager (see the docs), and then use

```js
import mySvgContent from "!!raw-loader!../path/to/image.svg";

function MyComponent ()
{
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: mySvgContent}} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using Nextjs 12 or newer, there is a simple solution.

In your `next.config.js` add this:

```
module.exports = {
    //another configs here
    images: {
        dangerouslyAllowSVG: true,
        contentSecurityPolicy: "default-src 'self'; script-src 'none'; sandbox;",
    }
}
```

i founded it [Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#dangerously-allow-svg)