# How to import SVG into Next.js component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-images

I am trying to import an SVG image from file into a Next.js component.

In the assets folder I have google.svg (icon):

```
<svg className="svgIcon-use" width="25" height="37" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
    <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
      <path
        d="M20.66 12.693c0-.603-.054-1.182-.155-1.738H12.5v3.287h4.575a3.91 3.91 0 0 1-1.697 2.566v2.133h2.747c1.608-1.48 2.535-3.65 2.535-6.24z"
        fill="#4285F4"
      />
      <path
        d="M12.5 21c2.295 0 4.22-.76 5.625-2.06l-2.747-2.132c-.76.51-1.734.81-2.878.81-2.214 0-4.088-1.494-4.756-3.503h-2.84v2.202A8.498 8.498 0 0 0 12.5 21z"
        fill="#34A853"
      />
      <path
        d="M7.744 14.115c-.17-.51-.267-1.055-.267-1.615s.097-1.105.267-1.615V8.683h-2.84A8.488 8.488 0 0 0 4 12.5c0 1.372.328 2.67.904 3.817l2.84-2.202z"
        fill="#FBBC05"
      />
      <path
        d="M12.5 7.38c1.248 0 2.368.43 3.25 1.272l2.437-2.438C16.715 4.842 14.79 4 12.5 4a8.497 8.497 0 0 0-7.596 4.683l2.84 2.202c.668-2.01 2.542-3.504 4.756-3.504z"
        fill="#EA4335"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

I need to import that SVG inside of this  inside of the Next.js component:

```
import googleLogo from '../assets/google.svg';

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LoginLayout title="Login Page">
        <div>
          <Link href="/auth/google">
            <a className="button">
              <div>
                <span className="svgIcon t-popup-svg">
                  {googleLogo}   // <---- import here icon
                </span>
                
              </div>
            </a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </LoginLayout>
    );
  }
}
```

I installed this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images

and set configuration based on that documentation in `next.config.js`:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass({
    webpack: (config) => config,
    distDir: '../_next'
  }),
  withImages({
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/assets/svg'),
    webpack(config, options) {
      return config;
    }
  })
);
```

Why my import of SVG does not work?

Comment: Why would you exclude the svg fodler you are trying to work with in your webpack config?

Comment: That is mistake, I didn't thing of that when i copy paste code.

Comment: After trying some configurations from the internet, I found it easy to pass the location of the svg image, to the `img` tag or `<Image />` imported from 'next/image'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Another approach would be to make a component for your svg. I like this approach because I can easily pass in props for width, height color etc if required on the svg.

```
//GoogleLogo.js
import React from "react";
export default function GoogleLogo() {
  return (
    <svg className="svgIcon-use" width="25" height="37" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
      <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
        <path
          d="M20.66 12.693c0-.603-.054-1.182-.155-1.738H12.5v3.287h4.575a3.91 3.91 0 0 1-1.697 2.566v2.133h2.747c1.608-1.48 2.535-3.65 2.535-6.24z"
          fill="#4285F4"
        />
        <path
          d="M12.5 21c2.295 0 4.22-.76 5.625-2.06l-2.747-2.132c-.76.51-1.734.81-2.878.81-2.214 0-4.088-1.494-4.756-3.503h-2.84v2.202A8.498 8.498 0 0 0 12.5 21z"
          fill="#34A853"
        />
        <path
          d="M7.744 14.115c-.17-.51-.267-1.055-.267-1.615s.097-1.105.267-1.615V8.683h-2.84A8.488 8.488 0 0 0 4 12.5c0 1.372.328 2.67.904 3.817l2.84-2.202z"
          fill="#FBBC05"
        />
        <path
          d="M12.5 7.38c1.248 0 2.368.43 3.25 1.272l2.437-2.438C16.715 4.842 14.79 4 12.5 4a8.497 8.497 0 0 0-7.596 4.683l2.84 2.202c.668-2.01 2.542-3.504 4.756-3.504z"
          fill="#EA4335"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
}
```

and in your file from above.

```
  import GoogleLogo from "./GoogleLogo";

  class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <LoginLayout title="Login Page">
          <div>
            <Link href="/auth/google">
              <a className="button">
                <div>
                  <span className="svgIcon t-popup-svg">
                    <GoogleLogo />
                  </span>

                </div>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </LoginLayout>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's greath solution, I like also. But need to do on the diff way. 
need to have that google.svg file which will contation svg partg of code, and import on that way.

Answer (score 9):

I've recently added this myself. I followed the example on the Next.js repo.

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/svg-components

There's a couple of steps -

1. You need to install the following dependency :

- babel-plugin-inline-react-svg

2. Inside your `.babelrc` you need to add the plugin `babel-plugin-inline-react-svg`

```
  "plugins": [
    "inline-react-svg",
  ]
```

You should then be able to import your SVG's into your components. Here's a gist of something similar I used it for.

https://gist.github.com/iamchristough/493c60112770058566d559e6860dc4c9

Note - you need to declare it as its own component `<GoogleLogo />` if you just did `{GoogleLogo}` it will error. Also there is an issue with how babel transforms the SVG so any changes inside the SVG file won't appear. You need to rename the file in order for the bundler to see a change.

Comment: cannot install "inline-react-svg" this does not exist in the npm registry

Comment: I don't think that `svg-inline-react` is needed, it's not related, non of the packages mention each other in any way.

Comment: Btw, the gist link is dead.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [@svgr/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) plugin to convert svg imports to react component.

This will allow you to do the following:

```js
import Icon from './icon.svg';

<Icon />
```

Comment: If you do this, don't forget to add @svgr/webpack in your webpack config inside next.config.js

Comment: This is my preferred method so far. You can read this article for more understanding https://frontend-digest.com/how-to-import-svgs-into-nextjs-8ec6100e613f

Answer (score 2):

I got SVGs working with this next.js config.

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })

    return config
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Code:**

```
webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [
        options.defaultLoaders.babel,
        {
          loader: "@svgr/webpack",
          options: {
            icon: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
```