# How to use SVG images inside a Next.js component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-images

In `next.config.js` - I added config which is needed for using SVG images.

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass(
    {
      webpack: (config) => config,
      distDir: '../_next'
    },
    withImages({
      webpack(config, options) {
        return config;
      }
    })
  )
);
```

And here is my SVG file, under next folders `/client/assets/googleIcon.svg`.

Maybe problem is in the SVG file. I don't have experience with SVG, is this SVG correct?

```
<svg version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
  <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
    <path
      d="M20.66 12.693c0-.603-.054-1.182-.155-1.738H12.5v3.287h4.575a3.91 3.91 0 0 1-1.697 2.566v2.133h2.747c1.608-1.48 2.535-3.65 2.535-6.24z"
      fill="#4285F4"
    />
    <path
      d="M12.5 21c2.295 0 4.22-.76 5.625-2.06l-2.747-2.132c-.76.51-1.734.81-2.878.81-2.214 0-4.088-1.494-4.756-3.503h-2.84v2.202A8.498 8.498 0 0 0 12.5 21z"
      fill="#34A853"
    />
    <path
      d="M7.744 14.115c-.17-.51-.267-1.055-.267-1.615s.097-1.105.267-1.615V8.683h-2.84A8.488 8.488 0 0 0 4 12.5c0 1.372.328 2.67.904 3.817l2.84-2.202z"
      fill="#FBBC05"
    />
    <path
      d="M12.5 7.38c1.248 0 2.368.43 3.25 1.272l2.437-2.438C16.715 4.842 14.79 4 12.5 4a8.497 8.497 0 0 0-7.596 4.683l2.84 2.202c.668-2.01 2.542-3.504 4.756-3.504z"
      fill="#EA4335"
    />
  </g>
</svg>
```

And on the end I am importing this file and tried to show image in the followign ways:

1. `{googleIcon}`
2. `<img src={googleIcon} />`

When I run the app I receive the following error:

```
./assets/googleIcon.svg 2:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to nest the `withImages` into `withSass` function. This is why these functions take `config` as argument.

If you need to provide each of these arguments, they can be combined into the most nested functions argument.

```
module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass(
    withImages({
      distDir: '../_next',
      webpack(config, options) {
        return config;
      }
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: Nice, I fixed that error, do you know maybe Why i am getting error: "Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: data:image/svg+xml;base64" ?

Comment: @MarkJames Aren't you trying the second method, `<img src={googleIcon} />`?

Comment: I tried and still does not work. Now webpack loader is not problem. Just images is not showed. I am getting that warning messages actualy is not error.

Comment: It's hard to tell from this, but this warning normally occurs when `base64` image is rendered directly in React, something like `{googleIcon}` can cause it

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to wrap your svg in a component, and then use the component:

```js
function Icon () {
  return (
    <svg version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
      <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
        <path
          d="M20.66 12.693c0-.603-.054-1.182-.155-1.738H12.5v3.287h4.575a3.91 3.91 0 0 1-1.697 2.566v2.133h2.747c1.608-1.48 2.535-3.65 2.535-6.24z"
          fill="#4285F4"
        />
        <path
          d="M12.5 21c2.295 0 4.22-.76 5.625-2.06l-2.747-2.132c-.76.51-1.734.81-2.878.81-2.214 0-4.088-1.494-4.756-3.503h-2.84v2.202A8.498 8.498 0 0 0 12.5 21z"
          fill="#34A853"
        />
        <path
          d="M7.744 14.115c-.17-.51-.267-1.055-.267-1.615s.097-1.105.267-1.615V8.683h-2.84A8.488 8.488 0 0 0 4 12.5c0 1.372.328 2.67.904 3.817l2.84-2.202z"
          fill="#FBBC05"
        />
        <path
          d="M12.5 7.38c1.248 0 2.368.43 3.25 1.272l2.437-2.438C16.715 4.842 14.79 4 12.5 4a8.497 8.497 0 0 0-7.596 4.683l2.84 2.202c.668-2.01 2.542-3.504 4.756-3.504z"
          fill="#EA4335"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Icon />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

If you really need to load svg as image, you need to configure your webpack.

```
npm install @svgr/webpack
```

Then:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  }
};
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175445/cant-import-svg-into-next-js#answer-55180310).

Comment: I can't do on that way, cus this image will be sent on aws S3 and that is reason why must be as svg file.

Comment: Then precise your question.

Comment: I updated my answer, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175445/cant-import-svg-into-next-js#answer-55180310

Comment: Problem is cus I can't show svg image.  I installed module which is for reading svg images. And that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

When I add `esModule: false` to options it works.

```
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 100000,
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      esModule: false,
    },
  },
});
```