# Importing SVG in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to import an svg within a NextJS project, everytime I get this error

```
./assets/aboutimg.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="578" height="1028" viewBox="0 0 578 1028">
|   <image id="_64538565_2370063099695596_8091233071539421184_n" data-name="64538565_2370063099695596_8091233071539421184_n" width="578" height="1028" xlink:href="
```

I have tried using next-images and also svgr. I will paste my About.js code below, it would be excellent if someone could let me know what I have been doing wrong.

```
import LayoutNoLogo from '../comps/LayoutNoLogo'
import AboutImg from '../assets/aboutimg.svg'

const About = () => {
    return (
        <LayoutNoLogo>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="column-1">
                    <img src={AboutImg} />
                </div>
                <div className="column-2">
                    <h1>About</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <style jsx>{`

        `}</style>

        </LayoutNoLogo>
    )
}

export default About;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175445/cant-import-svg-into-next-js

Comment: @sv12 I followed this and it still comes up with the same error

Comment: can you post your svg.js also?

Comment: `export default () => <div>
  <img src={require('../assets/aboutimg.svg')} />
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using next-images and adding the correct module exports allowed me to use images of all file types.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images

Comment: This shouldn’t be necessary in later versions of next next 9^

Answer (score 3):

I've finally used `file-loader` for using SVG images in my project.

1. install webpack and file loader : `yarn add webpack`, `yarn add file-loader -D`
2. in `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    //...other configs
    webpack: (config, {}) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
                test: [/\.svg$/, /\.woff$/],
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                    publicPath: `/_next/static/images/`, //specify the base path
                    outputPath: 'static/images', //and output path
                }
        })
    }
}
```

3. Now I can use `import img from '../assets/image.svg'`

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution testet with nextjs13

1. Install loader: `yarn add @svgr/webpack`
2. Update `next.config.js`

```js
webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      loader: '@svgr/webpack',
      options: {
        svgoConfig: {
          plugins: [
            {
              name: 'preset-default',
              params: {
                overrides: {
                  removeViewBox: false, // important
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });

    return config;
  },
```

Check fill prop (attribute) (svg, path etc.) & replace all values with `currentColor` for extending current text color (from css). Also you can remove all fill props from child tags, and extend it from parent svg.

```xml
<svg ... fill="currentColor">
...
</svg>
```

css:

```css
.icons-wrapper { color: red } /* fill all icons to red */
```

I prefer import icon dynamically in component:

```js
type AvailableIcons =
  | 'facebook' // ./svg/facebook.svg
  | 'google';

interface IProps {
  name?: AvailableIcons;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  className?: string;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

export const Icon = async ({ name, width, height, ...iconProps }: IProps) => {
  try {
    const Icon = await import(`./svg/${name}.svg`).then((icon) => icon.default); // lazy import
    return <Icon id={`svg-${name}`} width={width} height={height || width} {...iconProps} />;
  } catch (e) {
    return <>[Icon `{name}` not found!]</>;
  }
};
```

also you can import your svg component directly:

```js
import Logo from './svg/logo.svg'

const YourTestComponent = () => <>
   ...
   <Logo /* override props */ />
   ...
</>
```