# How to override Next.js `*.svg` module declaration?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, nextjs-image

Next.js has recently made a modification (in v11.0.x) which has the following type definitions:

In `next-env.d.ts` (non-modifiable, regenerated at every build):

```
/// <reference types="next" />
/// <reference types="next/types/global" />
/// <reference types="next/image-types/global" />
```

In `node_modules/next/image-types/global.d.ts` (non-modifiable, don't wanna use `patch-package`):

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any
  export default content
}
```

Now the issue is that I am using `@svgr/webpack`, and as a result I need to do the following:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: React.FC<React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>>
  export default content
}
```

Earlier placing this code in `index.d.ts` in the assets folder used to work. But now it doesn't and as result I am forced to cast every import separately. Any way to do this directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An alternative to replacing `next-env.d.ts` is to add an additional declarations file, e.g. `additional.d.ts`, as described in https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript.

As noted in the docs, this file must be included in the `include` array of your `tsconfig.json` file, but I've found the order is important as well - the additional file must be included **before** `next-env.d.ts`.

This seems to be because when there are multiple declarations for the same module containing default exports, the first declaration wins.

```js
// additional.d.ts
declare module "*.svg" {
  import React from "react";

  const content: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;

  export default content;
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["additional.d.ts", "next-env.d.ts"] // The order matters!
}
```

This gives our preferred type for SVGs, whilst preserving the other desirable behaviour from `next-env.d.ts`.

This seems preferable to simply replacing the built-in types file as the Next team have [reserved the right to adjust the types](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/26560#issuecomment-867661810) in future, meaning the copied types would be need to manually be kept up-to-date, and this approach doesn't seem to be a documented approach.

Answer (score 9):

I am using the following workaround:

- Add `next-env.d.ts` to exclude array in `tsconfig.json`:

  ```
  {
    // ...
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "next-env.d.ts"]
  }
  ```
- Add `next-env.d.ts` to `.gitignore`/`.eslintignore`.
- Create new file `custom.d.ts`:

  ```
  /// <reference types="next" />
  /// <reference types="next/types/global" />

  // additional things that one used to put here before Next.js v11
  ```
- Create new file `images.d.ts`:

  ```
  type StaticImageData = {
    src: string;
    height: number;
    width: number;
    placeholder?: string;
  };

  declare module '*.png' {
    const content: StaticImageData;
    export default content;
  }

  declare module '*.svg' {
    const content: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
    export default content;
  }

  declare module '*.jpg' {
    const content: StaticImageData;
    export default content;
  }

  declare module '*.jpeg' {
    const content: StaticImageData;
    export default content;
  }

  declare module '*.gif' {
    const content: StaticImageData;
    export default content;
  }

  declare module '*.webp' {
    const content: StaticImageData;
    export default content;
  }

  declare module '*.ico' {
    const content: StaticImageData;
    export default content;
  }

  declare module '*.bmp' {
    const content: StaticImageData;
    export default content;
  }
  ```
- Make sure that these files are handled by patterns specified in `include` array of `tsconfig`.
- Add declarations for `*.avif` too if you're using them in `next@12`:

  ```
  declare module '*.avif' {
    const content: StaticImageData
    export default content
  }
  ```

Comment: just wanted to say it works like a charm, way to go man, really clever solution, love it

Comment: Instead of excluding `next-env.d.ts` from `tsconfig.json`, [disabling static image import](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#disable-static-imports) disables the type declarations for images. In Next.js source code, [image-types/global.d.ts](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/image-types/global.d.ts) says `// this file is conditionally added/removed to next-env.d.ts
// if the static image import handling is enabled`

Comment: @TomoyukiAota That will disable importing non-svg images (i.e., png, jpg, etc.) too.