# Warning: Invalid attribute name: `'data-*'`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, next.js, react-typescript

I'm trying to import svg file in NEXT.js using [babel-plugin-inline-react-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg).

Followed all instructions and it **works fine**.

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["styled-components", { "ssr": true }],
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

```
// image.tsx

import styled from 'styled-components';
import BackgroundImage from '../public/assets/img.svg';
export const WhyChooseUsSection = () => {
    return <>
                <div className="background">
                    <BackgroundImage/>
                </div>
                <style jsx>{`
                    div {
                        position: relative;
                        width: 100%;
                    }
                `}</style>
            </>
}
```

```
// next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images')
module.exports = withImages()
```

But it occurs **warning**.

```
Warning: Invalid attribute name: `'data-name'`
```

Is this Because of Typescript? How can I fix it?

Comment: Where is this warning occurring? I can't see any attribute named `data-name` in your posted code. I guess it is present in your SVG file. Can you check that and add your `next.config.js` to your question?

Comment: Yes. there are`data-name` attributes in the SVG file. This is a large file so I couldn't write here.

Comment: @brc-dd I used `next-images`. Can I use these together?

Comment: Yes they can be used together. Although I guess `next-images` is somehow interfering with `babel-plugin-inline-react-svg` as the issue was [fixed](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg/pull/22) with the latter. Can you try editing your `next.config.js` to exclude `svg` files from `next-images`? Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images#file-extensions). If that too doesn't work then try setting the options of `inline-react-svg` same as this in your babelrc: https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg#options

Comment: I tried to edit `plugin-inline-react-svg` but it occurs error. ```TypeError: Property value of ObjectProperty expected node to be of a type ["Expression","PatternLike"] but instead got "JSXExpressionContainer"
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: What is your Next.js version? Also I didn't think you added it properly. Copy and paste this: https://pastebin.com/xTcs4aDM

Comment: @brc-dd Next version is 11.0.1

Comment: Then firstly you don't need `next-images` at all. Secondly, try configuring webpack instead as probably next.js new static import feature will cause issues with this. Change your `next.config.js` as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67641345/11613622 after installing the related packages.

Comment: https://duncanleung.com/next-js-typescript-svg-any-module-declaration/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67641345/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68129058/

Comment: Maybe if you provide us with the svg code we can check if everything is ok there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and was able to resolve by updating `plugins` in my .babelrc file. I updated it to match what is listed in the "options" section of the babel-plugin-inline-react-svg [README](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg).

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "inline-react-svg",
      {
        "svgo": {
          "plugins": [
            {
              "name": "removeAttrs", 
              "params": { "attrs": "(data-name)" }
            },
            "cleanupIDs"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```