# Having trouble importing the SVG from the cyrptoicons in REACT

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to REACT and playing around with project at the minute just brushing my skills up.

The problem is I'm having trouble importing icons from this **cryptoicons.co** site. I had success in another project with when I was using styled ICONS using this package **"https://styled-icons.js.org/"**.

it says in the github

```
You can then import the icons from ./node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons, for example ./node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/kmd.svg.
```

I've tried this but I can not get it to work at all.
when importing I get the icon back as an object but I need to render it as an SVG

```
{src: "/_next/static/image/node_modules/cryptocurrency-ic…g/black/AAVE.e6445d0682c7e011efb864fbefdc5239.svg", height: 32, width: 32}
```

height: 32
src: "/_next/static/image/node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/black/AAVE.e6445d0682c7e011efb864fbefdc5239.svg"
width: 32
**proto**: Object

they is a gap in my knowledge if someone could poke me in the right direction it would be helpful

I tried this to render the icon with no success

`<svg src={icon.src}></svg>`

Comment: Follow the second part of this answer (or the accepted answer on the thread if using webpack 4): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67641345/11613622 -- then you just need to do: ```import Aave from 'cryptocurrency-icons/svg/black/aave.svg';``` To render it simply do ```<Aave />```

Comment: Here is a sandbox demonstrating the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-river-s37pv?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer. you're example in codesandbox threw an error.

The method I used to solve was
  `import Image from "next/image"`
`<Image src={Aave}></Image>`