# How to display a svg image (hosted on cloudinary) with Next.js Image tag?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am building a project with Next.js and Strapi as CMS, the images are hosted on Cloudinary.

My problem is that the SVG image doesn't display using Image tag from Next.js.

I already read this topic [Can't import SVG into Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175445/cant-import-svg-into-next-js/63626899#63626899) but it's for locally stored images and doesn't seem to work for remote hosted SVG images.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My build is in Gatsby with Forestry.io as CMS and images hosted on cloudinary, but but my issue was solved by adding the `fl_sanitize` flag mentioned in [this article from cloudinary support](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000752672-SVG-files-in-Cloudinary-).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but stumbled across this post

I put out a Cloudinary integration for Next.js that wraps the Image component and you're able to handle this nicely

Next Cloudinary: https://next-cloudinary.spacejelly.dev/

Given an asset `cloudinary-logo-blue` that's uploaded as an SVG:

```
<CldImage
  width="500"
  height="96"
  src="cloudinary-logo-blue"
  format="svg"
/>
```

[image: Screenshot of SVG image loading in app]

Hope this helps!