# Can PhpStorm/WebStorm be made aware of custom loaders in Next.js's webpack config?

Tags: webpack, next.js, phpstorm

I use a custom webpack config as detailed in the [Next.js docs *Custom Webpack Config* page](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config). PhpStorm has [built-in support for handling webpack](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-webpack.html), however, since there is no actual webpack config file to point to, how does one integrate their IDE with a custom Next.js webpack config?

One issue I'm running into is PhpStorm complaining (rightfully) that the SVG I'm trying to import is not a module. However, this works because I'm using the `@svgr/webpack` loader. I'm assuming if I can get PhpStorm to "see" my webpack config, it won't complain about such things.

Having a command to generate a webpack config from `next.config.js`, for example, might be a viable workaround. Another is having a reference to a file that is dynamically resolved to the same config that the Next.js config file would use; [this is the approach taken by Vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#using-resolved-config-as-a-file).

As I'm using TypeScript, I have a `tsconfig.json` file at the root of my project, which serves to provide appropriate path aliasing and code/path completion.

The issue I'm running into is this:
[image]

The file `someSvg.svg` exists at the specified location, and the code runs as expected. However, PhpStorm is complaining. Is it possible to make PhpStorm aware of the fact that this import is being handled by webpack, specifically the `@svgr/webpack` loader?

Answer (score 0):

The IDE needs a resolved webpack config as a file for evaluation (like it's done in Vue Cli) to be able to resolve path aliases. If Next.js doesn't expose such configuration files, you can either add a simple dummy `js` file with aliases defined, like

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'myAlias': path.resolve(__dirname, './actual/path'),
...
    }
  }
}
```

to your project root and set it up as webpack configuration file, or define your aliases in `jsconfig.json` (also has to be placed in the root):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "myAlias/*": [
        "actual/path/*"
      ],
      "myOtherAlias/*": [
        "other/actual/path/*"
      ],
     ...
    }
  }
}
```

**Update:** Just noticed your updated question. The error comes from the Typescript compiler, it doesn't know how to deal with `.svg` files. You need adding a shim, a `.d.ts` file that will let the compiler know what it is. Like:
`types/shim.d.ts`:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
...
}
```

see [Can't import SVG into Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175445/cant-import-svg-into-next-js), for example

Comment: Since I'm using TypeScript and have a `tsconfig.json` file set up in the root of my project, aliases are working fine for me. I'm aware I can cherry-pick relevant bits of Next.js's webpack config into my own `webpack.config.js` file, but that doesn't appear to solve my problem with the custom loader, nor is that manual process ideal. I think I've run into the XY problem and will re-phrase my original question. I appreciate your help!

Comment: for Typescript projects, the IDE never uses webpack for aliases resolving, path mappings from `tsconfig.json` are used instead. So you don't need creating any dummy configs. Webpack support is about path aliases only, you can't expect any other stuff here, i.e. no special support for your custom loaders, etc.