# How to correctly export svg in react/next

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js

I am trying to add svg in my next project but i keep getting this error 'Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.'

code:index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image';
import {ReactComponent as Logo} from '/assets/Logo.svg';

const Header=()=>{
  return (
    <div className='flex'>
        <Logo/>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

svg file

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 74 20">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1{fill:#28b16d}
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path d="M51 13.53a.58.58 0 0 0-.11.08 2.77 2.77 0 0 1-2.28 1.1 4.79 4.79 0 0 1-2.32-.45 3.81 3.81 0 0 1-2.07-3 6.57 6.57 0 0 1-.07-1V6.07c0-.56.17-.73.73-.73h1.22c.49 0 .69.21.69.7v4.27a2.45 2.45 0 0 0 .5 1.56A2.25 2.25 0 0 0 51 11.3a1.13 1.13 0 0 0 .06-.41V6.06c0-.59.17-.76.75-.76H53c.49 0 .71.22.71.71v9.07a4.27 4.27 0 0 1-2.38 4 5.79 5.79 0 0 1-3.16.61 5.28 5.28 0 0 1-1.95-.45 1.23 1.23 0 0 1-.86-1.33v-.69a.44.44 0 0 1 .68-.43c.34.15.66.35 1 .48a3.87 3.87 0 0 0 2.42.16A2 2 0 0 0 51 15.46v-1.8a.54.54 0 0 0 0-.13zM24.34 5.55a13 13 0 0 1 1.32-.45 5.6 5.6 0 0 1 3.14.08 4.14 4.14 0 0 1 2.8 3.4 5.52 5.52 0 0 1-.09 2.62 4.48 4.48 0 0 1-2.8 3 6.13 6.13 0 0 1-5.76-.51 4.76 4.76 0 0 1-.73-.61 1.52 1.52 0 0 1-.48-1.08V1.71a.89.89 0 0 1 .48-.85l1.35-.79c.45-.26.77 0 .77.46V5.55zm0 4.3v1.83a.45.45 0 0 0 .22.42 3 3 0 0 0 2.35.47 2.27 2.27 0 0 0 1.85-1.48A3.61 3.61 0 0 0 29 9.44a2.55 2.55 0 0 0-.84-1.82 3.08 3.08 0 0 0-3.63.06.51.51 0 0 0-.13.34c-.07.61-.06 1.22-.06 1.83zM11.26-.07a7.34 7.34 0 0 1 6.91 5.77 7.41 7.41 0 0 1-4.36 8.48 7.16 7.16 0 0 1-8-1.79c-.4-.45-.41-.45-.92-.15l-3.33 2c-.57.33-.81.27-1.14-.3l-.31-.55a.64.64 0 0 1 .27-1l3.43-2c.52-.31.51-.3.35-.86A7.4 7.4 0 0 1 8.87.33a6.52 6.52 0 0 1 1-.26c.47-.07.93-.07 1.39-.14zm5.66 7.43a5.89 5.89 0 0 0-5.75-5.95 5.88 5.88 0 0 0-5.88 5.75A5.88 5.88 0 0 0 11 13.27a5.87 5.87 0 0 0 5.92-5.91zM39.91 13.43a1 1 0 0 0-.15.12 2.61 2.61 0 0 1-1.86 1.1 4.49 4.49 0 0 1-4.17-1.38 4.54 4.54 0 0 1-1.13-2.69 5.23 5.23 0 0 1 .47-3 4.6 4.6 0 0 1 3.13-2.42 7 7 0 0 1 5.28.64l.16.1a1.64 1.64 0 0 1 .9 1.62v6.07a2.13 2.13 0 0 1 0 .42.48.48 0 0 1-.5.42h-1.58c-.33 0-.52-.22-.55-.59v-.41zm0-5.63a.47.47 0 0 0-.25-.45A3.07 3.07 0 0 0 38.28 7a2.55 2.55 0 0 0-2.91 1.9 3.91 3.91 0 0 0 0 1.91A2.43 2.43 0 0 0 39.33 12a1.41 1.41 0 0 0 .57-1.22 59.2 59.2 0 0 1 0-2.98zM62.31 13.43a1.18 1.18 0 0 0-.16.14 2.52 2.52 0 0 1-1.73 1.07 4.54 4.54 0 0 1-3.22-.56 3.82 3.82 0 0 1-1.74-2.87 6.8 6.8 0 0 1-.07-1V6.02c0-.56.16-.73.73-.73h1.25A.59.59 0 0 1 58 6v4.29a2.46 2.46 0 0 0 .54 1.63 2.27 2.27 0 0 0 3.67-.63 1 1 0 0 0 0-.34V6.07c0-.56.18-.74.75-.74h1.19c.48 0 .69.22.69.7v7.69c0 .54-.2.74-.73.74H63c-.48 0-.67-.19-.68-.67l-.01-.36zM66.63 6.9V3.27a.85.85 0 0 1 .45-.81l1.35-.79.12-.06a.46.46 0 0 1 .68.44v2.89c0 .34 0 .35.36.35H73c.67 0 .81.14.82.8v.64c0 .44-.2.63-.63.64h-3.58c-.39 0-.39 0-.39.38v2.39a3.61 3.61 0 0 0 .15 1 2.09 2.09 0 0 0 2.3 1.44 2.52 2.52 0 0 0 1.45-.58l.13-.09a.51.51 0 0 1 .56-.1c.2.11.18.31.18.49v.85a1 1 0 0 1-.47.89 4 4 0 0 1-2.23.65 5 5 0 0 1-2.53-.56 3.91 3.91 0 0 1-2-3.08 16.67 16.67 0 0 1-.08-2c-.06-.72-.05-1.43-.05-2.15z" class="cls-1"/>
  <path d="M14.91 8.06v1.88c0 .43-.18.61-.61.61h-1.44c-.34 0-.49-.14-.49-.48V8.56a1.29 1.29 0 0 0-1.09-1.25 1.26 1.26 0 0 0-1.39 1 3.3 3.3 0 0 0 0 .69v1.06c0 .35-.15.52-.51.52h-1.5a.54.54 0 0 1-.6-.58V6.26a.73.73 0 0 1 .4-.71q1.42-.8 2.81-1.65a1.05 1.05 0 0 1 1.21 0c.94.57 1.9 1.13 2.85 1.68a.62.62 0 0 1 .34.6v1.91z" class="cls-1"/>
</svg>
```

I searched on the error and it says there is a problem with the import/export. So how should i export/import the file??

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Can't import SVG into Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175445/cant-import-svg-into-next-js)?

Answer (score 0):

You can using SVGR:
`npm install --save-dev @svgr/webpack`

After installation, create a next.config.js file at the root of your project directory and add the following basic webpack configuration.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
   config.module.rules.push({
   test: /\.svg$/i,
   issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
   use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
   })

 return config},
}
```

now you can import svg like this

```
import Icon from "./icon.svg";
const Example = () => <Icon />;
```