# Importing an SVG File in an Angular CLI Project?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg

It [works fine in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-circle?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

```
import circle from './circle.svg';
```

But when I try the exact same import in an Angular CLI project like this:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
```

VSCode displays the error:

```
Cannot find module './logo.svg'.ts(2307)
```

And Angular displays the error:

```
    ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(5,18): error TS2307: Cannot find module './logo.svg'.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: In your StackBlitz, you have the image in the same directory. In your angular project, do you have `logo.svg` file in the same directory? Angular is reporting that it couldn't find that file.

Comment: There is one mentioned svg import to typescript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717164/unable-to-import-svg-files-in-typescript

Comment: Yes `logo.svg` is in the same directory.

Comment: but, how does even the import work when there isn't export from the file ?? strange. Even stackblitz shows the same error, though it runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me was

```
const logo = require('./logo.svg') as string;
```

If it doesn't work, try:

```
const circle = require('!!raw-loader?!../assets/logo.svg') as string;
```

It will disable the default file loaders and return the file contents.

You can also import the file at runtime:

```
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('/assets/logo.svg', {responseType: 'text'})
      .subscribe(svg => console.log(svg));
  }
```

or use it as an image source:

```
<img src="logo.svg" />
```

Please note that your SVG won't work immediately as it has an invalid format. I had to add `version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` to the `<svg>` tag to make it display:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 104 104" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  ...
</svg>
```

Comment: When I log `logo` it logs `logo.svg` in other words it logs the name of the file instead of the content.  Does it log content for you?

Comment: No, the contents of the file. It also works in your Stackblitz: `const circle = require('./circle.svg'); console.log(circle);`, but first add dependency `@types/node`.

Comment: Odd - I log it like this in the constructor `    console.log(logo);` and it logs `logo.svg`.

Comment: I think you'll have to share your configuration files to have it solved here.

Comment: It's a brand new app.  I have all the configuration settings set to the defaults.  The `logo.svg` file is in the app folder.

Comment: I could push it to a github repository if need be.

Comment: I have added another way. It's not compile time loading of the file, but maybe that's enough for you?

Comment: The rawloader approach works as well.  Thanks again!