# What does `/// <reference types="react-scripts" />` mean? What other xml like syntax can we use in *.d.ts?

Tags: typescript

In normal *.d.ts file (definition files for typescript), we can normally use

```
declare ***

export interface ***
```

but there is also this

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
```

generated by create-react-app, what does it mean and can we actually use xml like syntax in *.d.ts files and what other syntax can we use?

Answer (score 20):

`/// <reference types="..." />` directive declares a dependency on a package.

The process of resolving these package names is similar to the process of resolving module names in an import statement. An easy way to think of these `triple-slash-reference-types` directives is as an import for declaration packages. For example, including `/// <reference types="node" />` in a declaration file declares that this file uses names declared in `@types/node/index.d.ts`. Thus, this package needs to be included in the compilation along with the declaration file.

Use these directives only when you are authoring a `d.ts` file by hand. More information on this can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).

In your particular case, `/// <reference types="react-scripts" />` imports various names declared in the `node_modules/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts` file.

Hope this information was somewhat informative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't understand how to define the path and name of d.ts including in compilation ? First example translate "node" -> @types/node/index.d.ts, but second translate "react-scripts"->react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should understand there are **TWO** mode when typescript instance see a file, *script mode* or *module mode*

In *script mode* everything is **global**, what is it meant by global? For example

```
/**
 * global.ts or whatever any name, 
 * you can put it ANYWHERE in your project
 * Typescript instance will ALWAYS find it 
**/
declare module '*.glsl' {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

So, how does a typescript instance know a file is global? The rule is quite simple, if there is no `export` or `import` presenting in the file, it is global, Otherwise, it is not!

```
/**
  import s from 'foo.glsl' from other file, can not work anymore
  Because no definition of *.glsl can be found
**/
declare module '*.glsl' {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}

/**
 * The export statement makes this file not "global" anymore!
 */
export type T=string
```

What should I do if I want to make use of other's declaration files in my project, `import` can not be used, it will invalidate all the current declarations.

So the answer is `/// <reference types="declaration.d.ts" />`, you can think of a kind of `import`, but it can keep the "globalness" of the file.

Actually, if you put `declaration.d.ts` anywhere in the project,  `<reference />` is not necessary at all, it should be global by default, just like any files without `export`/`export`

The `<reference />` is especially powerful when the desired declaration file resides in node_module which will not be visible by default