# How to replace /// with import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

If you use create-react-app a file named react-app-env.d.ts is created, that contains `/// <reference types="react-scripts" />`. I was completely redoing Eslint config that comes with create-react-app and while doing so, I have got an error saying:

> Do not use a triple slash reference for react-scripts, use import style instead  @typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference

My question is, how do I replace `/// <reference types="react-scripts" />` with `import`?

Comment: I would just omit that file when running eslint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60628874/what-does-reference-types-react-scripts-mean-what-other-xml-like-sy

Comment: So just to clarify the import part of it, if someone were to import it, in this instance the import would be `import 'react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts'` right?

Comment: Easiest way to ignore the file, is simply to create a .eslintignore file in the same folder as .eslintrc.json and put "react-app-env.d.ts"

Comment: Have you found a way to do this?

Comment: @Kr1 I did not have time to touch the project involved in this problem since, but it's essentially file for importing types regarding create-react-app from node-modules so importing it using `import 'react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts'` should, I don't know if it does, do the same thing. I remember also finding few questions suggesting what Konrad said, but cannot find them again, so I don't know about removing the file.

Comment: I tried the ```import 'react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts'``` way, but it' doesn't work unfortunately. So I just added an ESLint rule to ignore that error on this file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can replace it with `import 'react-scripts'` to fix this error.