# Dynamic SVG import not showing image using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, dynamic

I have created an **Icon Component** where it can load dynamic, seems like the SVG is not showing.

This is the sample

```
 function useDynamicSVGImport(name: string) {
  const ImportedIconRef = useRef<FunctionComponent<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<Error>();

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const importIcon = async (): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        ImportedIconRef.current = (await import(`../assets/${name}.svg`)).ReactComponent;
        console.log(`../assets/${name}.svg`);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);

        setError(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    importIcon();
  }, [name]);

  return { error, loading, SvgIcon: ImportedIconRef.current };
}
```

As per this [Answer tsconfig.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45887328/8177989) still it's not working

Comment: How do you render your icon?

Comment: I am making an enum and rendering from there @MichaelRovinsky