# How to import a folder of svg files into react as ReactComponents

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am making a real-time card game using react for my front-end (which was made using CRA), and I am storing all of my cards as .svg files in a subfolder in the src folder. I have seen in other questions that for single files you could use `import {ReactComponent as Image} from 'whatever.svg'` and for an entire folder to use `require.context()`. While the import statement works, the require.context method just provides me with `/static/media/whatever.randomStuff.svg` files that I can only import by making an http(s) request to that location on the site. I have tried using `@svgr/webpack` in the require.context function, but even when installed manually, it gives me the same output. Is there a way for me to use the import statement or something else to import all of the .svg files in that folder as ReactComponents in the file instead of having to make an http(s) request?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard

Comment: no. I was hoping to not have to explicitly name each svg file explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59901802/12549194) from another question. One thing I didn't know at the time of posting was that the version of webpack that react-scripts was using (v4.44.2) already had `@svgr/webpack`, so manually installing it with npm was essentially useless because it was probably already using it to generate the `/static/media/fileName.randomStuff.svg` files in the first place. In the end I used an intermediate file in the svg folder and did this:

```js
interface CardCache {
    [key: string]: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>>;
}
const cache: CardCache = {};

/* eslint import/no-webpack-loader-syntax: off */
const files = require.context("!svg-react-loader?name=card!./", true, /\.svg$/);

files.keys().forEach(path => {cache[path] = files(path)});

export {cache};
```

I used the eslint comment because I did not want to replace `react-scripts` with something like `react-app-rewired` just so I could have access to the `webpack.config.json` file.