# How to add custom ico or SVG as marker icon in @react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I am using [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) to show Google Map in my React Web application. Following their [documentation](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#marker) I have added the marker as follows.

> ```
>         <Marker
>             onLoad={onLoad}
>             position={location}
>             
>             icon={{
>                 // path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
>                 url:'./../../assets/svg/location_marker.svg',
>                 scale: 7,
>             }}
>         />
> ```

But it seems to be not working. There are no markers displayed. using `google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE` as `path` will show the marker icon. Did anyone face this issue before? any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added require and solved the issue.

```
    <Marker
        onLoad={onLoad}
        position={deliveryDestination}
        icon={{
            // path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            url: (require('./../../assets/svg/location_marker.ico')),
            fillColor: '#EB00FF',
            scale: 7,
        }}
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `.svg` you have to add `.default`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70964618/6505257

```
<MarkerF
    position={deliveryDestination}
    icon={{
        url: require('./../../assets/svg/location_marker.svg').default,
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the above methods don't work, Try this

```
<MarkerF options={{
                        icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/parking_lot_maps.png'
                    }}
                     />
```