# How to insert an SVG into a string in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I have a string coming from the server formatted like this:

"Lorem ipsum, <b>`#LOGO#` dolor</b> sit amet `#LOGO#` consectetur adipisicing elit `#LOGO#`."

I have to swap the `#LOGO#` substrings with an .svg in my assets folder.

I can't insert the component dynamically, since it's plain text. I also can't just convert the svg to a string constant, because it's used elsewhere as an `<img>` source. I can't import the .svg file since it's not a module:

```
import * as Icon from '@src/assets/icon.svg'
```

```
Cannot find module 'src/assets/icon.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I tried to add a 'gloabl.d.ts' or 'custom.d.ts' file to the project. VSCode stopped showing the error, but Angular didn't compile, showing the same error. Tried `require`'ing the file, but it's Angular, it doesn't allow that

The only approach that did work is to create a pipe that repalces the #LOGO# and pass the end result to the `innerHtml` attribute. But it just feels.. *wrong*

```
export class FormatPremRubPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(source: string): string {
    return source.replace(
      '#LOGO#',
      `<img src="/assets/logo.svg" />`
    );
  }
}
```

So what are my options?

Comment: Can you show some example code? From where the error is originating? This is crucial to get a clear "picture" . Whenever feasible include the code you are having questions about, struggle with and/or causes an error ☝

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import svg files in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717164/unable-to-import-svg-files-in-typescript)

Comment: @YoupBernoulli, there isn't much to show - the import statement itself throws this error

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler It didn't work. Either I'm missing something or the solution doesn't work for Angular

Comment: You might check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717164/unable-to-import-svg-files-in-typescript, specifically the answer "Solution without webpack and custom.d.ts"

Comment: @BrandonTaylor, nope, `Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try npm i --save-dev...`

Comment: Did you try adding @types/node? What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @Welnyr well... later (checked the audit traill/history of the question) you added the statement that throw the error. That's just what I meant.